# Can anyone explain me this part of the code

Tags: c++, function, callback

It is a callback function but I can't figure out how this part works

> if (cb_onPress) { cb_onPress(*this); }   //fire the onPress event

```
class Button;
typedef void (*buttonEventHandler)(Button&);

class Button {
  public:
 //code
   private:
 //code
 buttonEventHandler  cb_onPress;
};

 void Button::process(void)
 {
  //code
    if (cb_onPress) { cb_onPress(*this); }   //fire the onPress event

 }       

void Button::pressHandler(buttonEventHandler handler)
{
  cb_onPress = handler;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cb_onPress` is a pointer to a function returning `void` and taking a `Button&` parameter. It could point to something like this:

```
void foo(Button&){ std::cout << "Foo Button!\n"; }
```

This line, inside a `Button` member function,

```
if (cb_onPress) { cb_onPress(*this); }
```

checks that the pointer to function is not null, and if so, calls it, passing the same instance of `Button` as parameter (that is what passing `*this` achieves).

Example of use:

```
Button b;
b.pressHandler(foo);  // sets cb_onPress to point to foo
....
b.process();          // Prints "Foo Button"
```

although presumably the call to process happens internally, in response to a n event.

Comment: For my own enlightment... shouldn't it be (*cb_onPress)(*this)? I tried both and got no complains for either of them with g++

Comment: @jsantander AFAIK the two are equivalent. I choose the less verbose option.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cb_onPress) { cb_onPress(*this); }
```

`cb_onPress` is a pointer to a function.  If the pointer's a `nullptr` you can't call it, so the code checks it's not beforehand.

The overall supported client usage is like this:

```
void myButtonEventHandler(Button& b) { ...do something when pressed... };

Button button;  // make a button
button.pressHandler(myButtonEventHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

> if (cb_onPress)

checks if cb_onPress is null pointer. In other words checks if that function was defined before. If it isn't then it calls function

> cb_onPress

on that object